# How do you bind a RichTextBox's Rtf property to a RTF resource at design time?

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that I wish to fill with RTF text at design time.  This does **not** mean doing this:

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"<a bunch of rich text>";
```

which actually assigns the value at run time (or does it?).

I have created a project resource file called "TextResources.resx" with a resource named InstructionsRTF with a Value containing the rich text.  How is this to be bound to the RichTextBox at design time?

**Edited to add:**

@hans-passant is correct, although the exact code I ended up using differs somewhat:

```
rtfInstructions.Rtf = TextResoures.InstructionsRTF;
```

where TextResources is the TextResources.resx in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextBox doesn't support binding.  If it is already a precooked resource then trying to support this at design time doesn't make sense.  It is just one line of code in the form constructor:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Rtf = Properties.Resources.instructionsRTF;
    }
```

If you want to get more adventurous at design time then that's possible too.  You can create a UITypeEditor that lets you edit the RTF at design time.  Code [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984875/is-it-possible-to-style-text-in-a-richtextbox-at-design-time/2985687#2985687).

Comment: Augezeichnet! Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do German users have English user names?  Odd.  Isn't it "Aus"?

Comment: I'm American, but I am fairly fluent in German, and since I recognized your name as probably German...

Comment: Garlic cross, no, I'm Dutch.  We don't like them very much, just their money.

Comment: Hey! Watch it, my wife's from there! :-)  I lived briefly in Brunssum in Limburg long time ago -- wonderful country you have.  Found it a bit hard to understand the spoken language, but written Nederlands wasn't too difficult to puzzle out.  Bedankt voor uw hulp!

Comment: My first girlfriend was from Limburg.  Rimburg, pretty close to Brunssum.  Her family moved to the city I lived in after the mines got close down and we met at my school.  Language was indeed difficult, they spoke Limburger at dinner.  Only 223 kilometers on the map, a world away from the words I knew.  I made an effort to learn the dialect but only really got the swear words down pat.  Lek mich am asch!  Words weren't actually that important at the time, I was 17 and pretty doggone horny all the time :)

Comment: Ah, such is youth!  Wasted on the young.  Nice chatting with you!